# Gradle test case

Tags: java, unit-testing, encoding, gradle

I created a test unit that will simply print a String, that String value is "/UFFFD/UFFD0"(some non ascii characters).
when I execute my test case using IntelliJ the result is the unicode characters but when I do it via gradle I got "??", investigating deeper it's not just a display issue in fact the byte code of the two character changed to be the ? ascii character.
Any thoughts ?
PS: adding

```
    compileJava {options.encoding = "UTF-8"}
compileTestJava {options.encoding = "UTF-8"}
```

doesn't resolve my issue

Comment: can you provide a self contained example (e.g. on github) so I can have a closer look on what's going wrong there?

Comment: In fact I resolvde the issue with adding : test {
    systemProperty "file.encoding", "utf-8"
}